# Writing command line ouput into text file

Tags: java

I want to execute the below command and write the output into a text file,

```
sdcli unittest -imp -repo TEST_DB -file D:\UnitTestCase\UTF_AMS_CALCULS_4.xml
```

I used below code,

```
FileWriter writer= new FileWriter("D:\\output.txt", true);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec"CMD", "/C", + sdcli unittest -imp -repo TEST_DB -file D:\UnitTestCase\UTF_AMS_CALCULS_4.xml);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       writer.write(line + "\n");
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

But it is not working.

I tried manually also,

```
sdcli unittest -imp -repo TEST_DB -file D:\UnitTestCase\\UTF_AMS_CALCULS_4.xml > D:\output.txt
```

Instead of writing output in the log file it is printing in command prompt.

If I use the same code for another command, then it is writing into the text file. For this command output is not writing.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.setOut` it reassigns the "standard" output stream. Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) for more.

`System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("A.txt")));`

Edit: I read about the stdout redirection not working, you can try the *error redirection* `2>` as shown [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) for windows